# Problema al Pausar un Cronometro en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentado crear un cronometro en Android Studio usando Java. Aún soy un novato asi que probablemente haya una falla trivial en el codigo que cause el problema.

La aplicación consiste de un cronometro simple y un boton que inicia y pausa el conteo.

Cuando presiono el botón "Stop", el texto del boton cambia a "Start", la variable de control cambia, etc. El problema sucede cuando presiono el boton "Start" nuevamente, el cronómetro salta al tiempo transcurrido durante la pausa.

En otras palabras, si pauso a los 16 segundos, y espero 10 segundos para reanudar el cronometro, este salta a los 26 segundos y continua.

Espero que puedan resolver mi duda ya que por mas que busqué no encontré una solución, o talvez no se como encontrarla.

Adjunto el codigo y espero sus sugerencias.

Gracias.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.os.SystemClock;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Chronometer chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometerExample);

        final Button buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartChronometer);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean isRunning = false;
            boolean isFirstRunning = true;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isFirstRunning == true) {
                    long systemCurrTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    chronometer.setBase(systemCurrTime);
                    isRunning = true;
                    isFirstRunning = false;
                    buttonStart.setText("Stop");
                    chronometer.start();
                } else {
                    if (isRunning == true) {
                        chronometer.stop();
                        isRunning = false;
                        buttonStart.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        chronometer.start();
                        isRunning = true;
                        buttonStart.setText("Stop");

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Button buttonRestart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRestartChronometer);
        buttonRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                long systemCurrTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                chronometer.setBase(systemCurrTime);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes guardar el valor cuando lo paras y hacer luego la diferencia te dejo la solución par que lo revises.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.os.SystemClock;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Long chronStateSave = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Chronometer chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometerExample);
    final Button buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartChronometer);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean isRunning = false;
        boolean isFirstRunning = true;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isFirstRunning == true) {
                long systemCurrTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                chronometer.setBase(systemCurrTime);
                isRunning = true;
                isFirstRunning = false;
                buttonStart.setText("Stop");
                chronometer.start();
            } else {
                if (isRunning == true) {
                    chronStateSave = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    chronometer.stop();
                    isRunning = false;
                    buttonStart.setText("Start");
                } else {
                    long intervalOnPause = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronStateSave);
                    chronometer.setBase( chronometer.getBase() + intervalOnPause );
                    chronometer.start();
                    isRunning = true;
                    buttonStart.setText("Stop");

                }
            }
        }
    });

    Button buttonRestart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRestartChronometer);
    buttonRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            long systemCurrTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            chronometer.setBase(systemCurrTime);
        }
    });
}
```

}