# Pausar y reanudar CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código de la clase `Reloj` que extiende de `CountDownTimer`, que es un contador regresivo, cuando le doy stop se reinicia desde el valor inicial, mi interés es que retome el valor en donde lo pause.

Este es mi código:

```
public class Reloj extends CountDownTimer  {

    TextView imp; 

    public Reloj(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,TextView imp) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.imp = imp;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        imp.setText((l/1000)+"");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        imp.setText("Finaliza despues de los 10 seg.");
    }
}
```

dentro de la clase main tengo lo siguiente :

```
    btnStart1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart1);


    imprime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMuestra);

    imprime.setText("10");

    r1 = new Reloj(10000, 1000, imprime);


}

public void start(View v) {

    r1.start();

}

public void stop(View v) {
    r1.cancel();


}
```

Comment: Aqui tienes la misma duda resuelta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279514/problema-al-pausar-un-cronometro-en-android/279540#279540

Comment: Pero esa pregunta usa la clase "Chronometer"  esta pregunta usa un "CountDownTimer ".

Comment: @solamente, no logro entenderlo , la respuesta que me pasas usa Chronometer, te agradezco tu tiempo!

Answer (score 0):

#### CountDownTimer con pausa y reanudar

En realidad la clase `CountDownTimer` es muy limitada, podrías sobreescribir `onTick()` u `onFinish()` pero es lo único que podrías realizar.

```
package android.os;

public abstract class CountDownTimer {
    public CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public final synchronized void cancel() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public final synchronized CountDownTimer start() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public abstract void onTick(long var1);

    public abstract void onFinish();
}
```

Una forma de realizar algo similar es usando la implementación de [Gautier Hayoun](https://gist.github.com/Gautier) que hace uso de un Handler.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public abstract class CustomCountDownTimer {

    private static final String TAG = CustomCountDownTimer.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int MSG = 1;
    private long mStopTimeInFuture;
    private long mMillisInFuture;
    private final long mTotalCountdown;
    private final long mCountdownInterval;
    private long mPauseTimeRemaining;

    public CustomCountDownTimer(long millisOnTimer, long countDownInterval) {
        mMillisInFuture = millisOnTimer;
        mTotalCountdown = mMillisInFuture;
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
    }

    public final void cancel() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    public synchronized final CustomCountDownTimer create() {
        
        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            //End CountDownTimer
            onFinish();
        } else {
            mPauseTimeRemaining = mMillisInFuture;
        }

        //Start CountDownTimer!
        resume();

        return this;
    }

    public void pause () {
        if (isRunning()) {
            mPauseTimeRemaining = timeLeft();
            cancel();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        if (isPaused()) {
            mMillisInFuture = mPauseTimeRemaining;
            mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
            mPauseTimeRemaining = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isPaused () {
        return (mPauseTimeRemaining > 0);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return (!isPaused());
    }

    public long timeLeft() {
        long millisUntilFinished;
        if (isPaused()) {
            millisUntilFinished = mPauseTimeRemaining;
        } else {
            millisUntilFinished = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            if (millisUntilFinished < 0) millisUntilFinished = 0;
        }
        return millisUntilFinished;
    }

    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    public abstract void onFinish();


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            synchronized (CustomCountDownTimer.this) {
                long millisLeft = timeLeft();
                
                if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                    cancel();
                    onFinish();
                } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                    // no tick, just delay until done
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                } else {
                    long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    onTick(millisLeft);
                    // take into account user's onTick taking time to execute
                    long delay = mCountdownInterval - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTickStart);
                    // special case: user's onTick took more than mCountdownInterval to
                    // complete, skip to next interval
                    while (delay < 0) delay += mCountdownInterval;

                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

---

En el caso de tu código de esta forma podrías inicializar la clase `CustomCountDownTimer` :

```
private CustomCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    countDownTimer = new CustomCountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            imprime.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
             imprime.setText("Finaliza despues de los 10 seg.");
        }
    };

}
```

para controlar la pausa y la reanudación del conteo:

```
public void start(View v) {

    //Si esta pausado reinicia.   
    if(countDownTimer.isPaused()){
       countDownTimer.resume();
    }else { //Inicia por primera vez.
       countDownTimer.create();
    }

}

public void stop(View v) {

   countDownTimer.pause();

}
```